# What is the most basic thing?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, physics, universe

I wanted to know that what is the most basic or the basicestest thing that makes up the universe? Just like a wall is made up of bricks and bricks are made up of atoms and atoms are made up of subatomic particles, what would be the last thing we would encounter? Is it a mass or a massless thing or a phenomenon or what?

Comment: You actually expect an answer to that???

Comment: This question ounds like one of the big hopes of the study of physics, that is, to find the Grand Universal Theory, or Theory of Everything.

Comment: Since you’re restricting your purview to physical systems (per the comments you left under answers), this question is one for physics, not philosophy. The currently best-known answer to physicists is [the elementary particles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle), but like all scientific answers it is contingent, and we should expect our understanding to change over time (or there’s no point in experimentation!). String theory was an attempt at this, for example.

Comment: After additional research about your question, the answer is --- 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get an answer, the only answer I can give is, the "Consciousness".

From your question I guess that your question is, "Where will we stop when we explore the root of everything?".

You know that when we go deeper into a thing we get things that cannot stay in one particular atom as you imagine, isn't it? Its subtlety becomes  unimaginable.    What I said is just for guiding your imagination; **not for any kind of comparison**.

Since you can **never** go beyond it, "Consciousness" is the basic of all things...if you wish to get ONE such thing. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_(consciousness). You would get the answer to your last 2 questions from this link.

Comment: Nope, I think. The answer should be something physical.

Comment: If it were purely physical it wouldn't be an answer to your question.

Comment: Haven't you heard this, "Observation affects the particle being observed." Then would you say that they are not physical? 1.  https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/nov/10/what-is-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle  2.  https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1998/02/980227055013.htm

Comment: Please note my two comments given above.  If so, what is the significance of the observer in physics?

Comment: @SonOfThought The answer in physics is “the observer necessarily interacts with the system being observed, and therefore inevitably changes the state he was trying to observe”. In physics, there is no need to invoke consciousness (and indeed metaphysical influences are explicitly excluded as being untestable); the observer is merely the external system that interacts with the system of interest. An observer could be a photon or a probe; consciousness is orthogonal to this.

Comment: If by the term 'observer' you mean a completely physical thing how would the observer understand a thing which is physical?   So, when you observe something, it implies that a consciousness is  behind these.  If you say, 'the subtlest form has no consciousness', how is it possible to constitute a observer?   What is the logic behind it?  When consciousness works through our senses it will certainly create delusion.

Comment: @SonOfThought You got it “a completely physical thing”. There is *no* implication of a understanding on the observer’s part. Despite its gloss in other context, in the physics you’re talking about, and the physical term “observer” does *not* require or imply consciousness or understanding. Waveforms collapse from interactions. Does not require mind or thought.  It may be confusing because the meaning of “observer” *outside* these contexts does involve a thinking being. But in physics it doesn’t.

Comment: Yes, physics is not basic and cannot find consciousness. 'Basic' or fundamental questions belong in metaphysics. Still, some physical objects may be more basic than others. .

Comment: Did you notice the last statement in my comment? It is because of delusion that we are unaware of consciousness. Yes, 'basic' or fundamental questions belong to metaphysics.  Physics alone can't answer it.

Comment: Logged into my account after 5 years, now I understand ;)
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

By 'thing' I presume you mean 'form'. The most basic 'form' is not basic and this is a matter of logic. Form cannot originate with form unless we want an infinite regress.

I don't know what the most basic thing is, needless to say.

Comment: I meant 'some physical thing'.